# Opposite for desideratum to mean "something not wished for"

Tags: philosophy-terms

Desideratum means "something that is desired", and quite often is used in philosophy to refer to the subject of a philosophical investigation. ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/desideratum), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desideratum))

I want another word, preferably Latin, that means "*something not [specifically] wished for*." For instance, a theory is answering some questions (which can be interesting in and of itself) while the questions have not been asked in the first place. Not that the answer is toxic/hated, but it simply doesn't interest the listener.

The only things I've already found (like [here](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/speaking-in-tongues/topics/what-is-the-opposite-of-a-desideratum)) suggests opposites with very negative meaning, like anathema or abhorrent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find something not wished for (*desideratum*), then surely it is irrelevant?

The word for this, then, is *alienus*, whuch used substantively becomes *alienum*. Otherwise, a phrase such as *nihil ad rem*, roughly 'not to the point' should serve.

Comment: The latter seems a better fit (as the case I'm trying to convey is like someone having an answer, walking in the streets looking for a question for it.) Thanks!